# Repeating a question when answer is wrong

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

So I basically have to create a small quiz however I'm unsure on how i would re ask the question I would use when the answer is wrong. I believe its a loop but I'm lost on which one. This is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main() {
  std::string answer;

  cout << "Is K before T in the alphabet ?";

  cin >> answer;

  if (answer == "y") {
    cout << "Well done!";
  }

  else {
    cout << "Try again";
  }
```

Comment: I would advise a while loop https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a simple boolean control variable:

```cpp
int main()
{         
    std::string answer;
    bool isCorrect = false;

    
    while(isCorrect == false)

    {   std::cout << "Is K before T in the alphabet ?";
        std::cin >> answer;
        
        if (answer == "y")
        {
            isCorrect = true;        
            std::cout << "Well done!";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Try again";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't ask the question again. You'd need to move printing part inside the loop

Comment: OP asked how to repeat the question. You need to move question output inside the loop for the answer to be correct. Also fix your typos.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on having several questions, you can create a helper function and then call it for each question:

```
bool inputValidation(std::string strQuestion, std::string strAnser) {
    std::string userInput;
    std::cout << strQuestion;
    std::cin >> userInput;
    while (true) {
        if (userInput == strAnswer)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << strQuestion;
            std::cin >> userInput;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    bool correct = InputValidation("What is the answer?","42");
    correct = InputValidation("Is K before T in the alphabet?", "yes");
}
```

Then you can put all your questions and answers in a map and use a for each loop to cycle through each question-answer pair. If you need multiple outputs, say, "y" == "Yes" == "1", you can pass a `vector<std::string>` as the answer.